# TFS local vs cloud

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I just started with Team Foundation server and read different tutorials then tried it on default cloud server. As there is mentioned that we can only use team foundation server FREE up to 5 members. That is why I want to setup TFS on my server.

Please suggest me should I go for it ?

Is there any advantages of using TFS on cloud instead using it on my own local server?

Also is there any GOOD tutorial to setup TFS on my machine and enable it for my other team members remotely ? ( I am following [this](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/installing-tfs-2012-on-server-2012-with-sql-2012/) ) .

Zauk

Comment: This is [not a constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) question for Stack Overflow's format, but [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2013/01/17/team-foundation-server-vs-team-foundation-service.aspx) may help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TF Service is a nice way to get up and running quickly, without worrying about infrastructure, backups, etc.  What you lose is some customization, lab management, and SSRS reporting, [more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2013/01/17/team-foundation-server-vs-team-foundation-service.aspx):

[image]
So which one to use is depending on your situation.

For tutorial on Install TFS

Just take a look on my 2 **Guides** about installing TFS 2012 and 2010, you will find step-by-step tutorial that explain to you exactly what you should do and how to verify every steps before moving to the next one, they have videos and documents with every detail steps needed.

I recommended to have a look on the whole sections because sometimes service accounts used for configuring different TFS components are very important.

[TFS 2012 Guide](http://tfs2012visualguide.codeplex.com/)

[TFS 2010 Guide](http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks M.Radwan -MVP    its helpful :).